# Iteratively assigning variables in Python

Tags: python, scope, variable-assignment

Never mind the placeholder variable names; how do I assign to D, E, and F in the way that I'm trying to do here?

```py
print("Input 3 search coordinates")
D, E, F, = 0, 0, 0
    for axes in [[D, "Y"], [E, "X"], [F, "Z"]]:
        while True:
            try: 
                axes[0] = int(input("{}-Axis: ".format(axes[1])))
                break
            except:
                print("No, a natural number!")
        print(axes)
print(str(D) + str(E) + str(F))
```

This little bit of print debugging at the end outputs "000," rather than the inputs, like "444." What do I need in order to assign the inputs to the variables in the list being looped through (while also not repeating myself)?

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables, **just use a container** like a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: The list element does not remember that its initial value came from the variable `D`; assigning a new value to the list element leaves `D` undisturbed.

Comment: @JohnGordon As a question of academic interest, what is the compiler doing with the first and second `D`?
(Is there a way to turn a Python into the assembly of the C from the compilation, or would that be wildly unreadable?)

Comment: The way this code is organized, I don't think you can retrieve the input values, because you didn't assign a name to the outer list.  The only name you have access to is `axes`, which will contain only the last sub-list when the for loop is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_input(axis):
    while True:
        user_input = input(f"{axis}-Axis: ")
        try:
            axis_int = int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            break
    return axis_int

print("Input 3 search coordinates")
x, y, z = [get_input(axis) for axis in "XYZ"]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a `dictionary` instead:

- Replace the `list` with a `dict`, then call the `key` to update the `value`
- Dictionaries are a better `data type` for situations where named variables (e.g. `x`, `y`, `z`) are being updated.

  - More about [Basic Data Types in Python](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/)

```
coor_dict = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}

for k in coor_dict.keys():
    while True:
        try:
            coor_dict[k] = int(input(f'{k}-Axis: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('No, a natural number!')

print(coor_dict)
```

#### Output of execution:

```
x-Axis:  4
y-Axis:  5
z-Axis:  6
{'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6}
```